# This is how google bot see my webpage (as seen in webmaster tool - fetch as google)

Tags: joomla, fetch

I have a joomla website. In my google webmaster tools, this is how google bots fetched my the disclaimer page on my site. What does it mean? I don't see any content here.

My real page is this: http://www.asklaw.in/disclaimer.
(I am referring to this page as an example. Other pages also do not show any conetnt)

I don't see any content on this page as fetched by google bot.

> **Fetch as Google**
>
> This is how Googlebot fetched the page. URL:
>   http://www.asklaw.in/disclaimer
>
> Date: Friday, February 14, 2014 at 12:32:33 AM PST
>
> Googlebot Type: Web
>
> Download Time (in milliseconds): 407
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Server: nginx/1.4.5
>
> Date: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 08:32:34 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Set-Cookie:
>   226d2339faeab0a35cea40673655bfc1=ea6579466180b66de9e73781d5179047;
>   path=/ Cache-Control: max-age=3600
>
> Expires: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 09:32:34 GMT
>
> Content-Encoding: gzip
>
> **jos-Warning**:
>   JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_COMPONENT_NOT_LOADING
>  
>  JSite ->
>   initialise() @ /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/index.php:30
>   JApplication -> initialise() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/includes/application.php:116 JApplication -> triggerEvent() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:230 JDispatcher -> trigger() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:642 JEvent -> update() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/event/dispatcher.php:161 call_user_func_array() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/event/event.php:71 plgSystemAdmintoolsPro -> onAfterInitialise()
>   plgSystemAdmintoolsPro -> IPFiltering() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/plugins/system/admintools/admintools/pro.php:136 JError :: raiseError() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/plugins/system/admintools/admintools/pro.php:676 JError :: raise() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251 JError :: throwError() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:176 call_user_func_array() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:214 JError :: handleCallback()
>  call_user_func() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:765 plgSystemRedirect :: handleError()
>  JError ::
>   customErrorPage() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/plugins/system/redirect/redirect.php:109 JDocumentError -> render() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:798 JDocumentError -> _loadTemplate() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/document/error/error.php:107 require_once() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/document/error/error.php:135 require() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/templates/yoo_nano3/error.php:19 Warp\Joomla\Helper\SystemHelper -> init() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/templates/yoo_nano3/warp.php:33 Warp\Joomla\Helper\SystemHelper -> initSite() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/templates/yoo_nano3/warp/systems/joomla/src/Warp/Joomla/Helper/SystemHelper.php:119 JSite -> getParams() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/templates/yoo_nano3/warp/systems/joomla/src/Warp/Joomla/Helper/SystemHelper.php:139 JComponentHelper :: getParams() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/includes/application.php:358 JComponentHelper :: getComponent() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:92 JComponentHelper :: _load() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:43 JError :: raiseWarning() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:415 JError :: raise() @
>   /home4/pawanhg/public_html/asklaw.in/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:276

Comment: Google is seeing a warning that is being thrown by you_nano3. If you turned on error reporting you would  see it too. Get the error message and then ask for help from the Warp support forums.

Answer (score 1):

JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_COMPONENT_NOT_LOADING is what you need to investigate further.

This Joomla Forum posts indicates the issue may be with having uninstalled a component, or perhaps not having the latest version installed, and there being a bug - http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=579&t=578754

Example components mentioned include Kunena forum component, Zoo Theme templates and extensions (which you have as the Warp template framework is theirs), and some others.

If you had that installed, it may not have not removed everything and that is then triggering the page to look for something else.

Check anything you've removed was removed entirely (components, plugins, modules).